# Why does Ubuntu have a 6-month release cycle?

Tags: release, ubuntu, development-cycle

Why has Ubuntu committed to a 6-month release cycle? Why should it have a fixed cycle at all?

Doesn't that go against the "if it ain't broken don't fix it" saying?

Comment: The LTS version (Long Term Supported) renews every 2 years. The current LTS is 10.04 Lucid Lynx.

Comment: The server LTS is supported for even longer than that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TimeBasedReleases#Why does Ubuntu use time-based releases?](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TimeBasedReleases#Why%20does%20Ubuntu%20use%20time-based%20releases?)

> Ubuntu releases are challenging because they represent an aggregation of the work of thousands of independent software projects. We feel that a time-based release process enables us to provide our users with the best balance of the latest software, tight integration, and excellent overall quality.

I agree personally that frequent releases is the best way to get software out to users.  The problem is that to make a good release you need to do thorough testing which takes time and effort.  The 6 months cycle is the compromise Ubuntu chose.

Comment: Should've read the Wiki before asking, thanks a lot!

Comment: The trick is knowing what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you install a new version, things break. I am running 10.04 LTS. I assume that anything that apt-get upgrades will not break my code. If I upgraded to 10.09 libraries move, directories change, things will break, and for what? Latest features? No thanks. LTS is good for servers which need stability more than anything else.

I expect 12.04 to be LTS.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS

Comment: How are you upgrading? The only problem I've ever had with an upgrade was getting my partitions mixed up once and blasting my home and var directories - all the rest have been smooth as butter